# ObjectdispsoedException was unhandled Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Texture2D'

Tags: c#, xna

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ButtonGame
{
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    MouseState mouse, prevMouse;

    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    public IAsyncResult result;
    public Object stateobj;
    public bool GameSaveRequested = false;
    public GamePadState currentState;

    public class GameImages
    {
        //Image Diminsions and Graphic
        public Texture2D texture;
        //Images position on the Viewport
        public Vector2 position = new Vector2(0, 0);

    }//GameImages
    GameImages button;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
        graphics.PreferMultiSampling = false;
        graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
    }//Game1()

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        button = new GameImages();
        base.Initialize();
    }//Initialize

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        //Gives the button the graphic "button.PNG" from resources
        button.texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Button");
        //Sets the drawing point of the button to the middle of the screen
        button.position = new Vector2(300, 400);
    }
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //Gets current position and condition of the mouse
        mouse = Mouse.GetState();
        //Makes the cursor visible on the screen of the game
        this.IsMouseVisible = true;
        //If the User has released the Left mouse button and previously had it pressed, (Left Clicked)
        if (mouse.LeftButton == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Released && prevMouse.LeftButton == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            //Check if the mouse was within the bounds of GameImage button
            if (CheckForClick(button))
            {
                //Remove the button from view
                button.position = new Vector2(5000, 5000);
            }
            if (mouse.Y > 600)
            {
                button.texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Catch - Red");
            }
        }

        if (mouse.X < 50)
        {
            button.position.X += 3;
        }
        else if (mouse.X > 500)
        {
            button.position.X -= 3;
        }
            //If the User has released the Right mouse button and previously had it pressed, (Right Clicked)
        else if ((mouse.RightButton == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Released && prevMouse.RightButton == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Pressed))
        {
            //Bring Back the button
            //button.position = new Vector2(300,400);
            InitiateSave();
        }
        else if ((mouse.MiddleButton == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Released && prevMouse.MiddleButton == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Pressed))
        {
            InitiateLoad();
        }
        //Store the current mouse position and conditon into a orevious state to prepare for new input
        prevMouse = mouse;
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }//Update

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        //Background Color
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        //if button is not off the screen
        if (button.position != new Vector2(5000, 5000))
        {
            //Draw the button
            DrawImage(button);
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }//Draw
    public void DrawImage(GameImages image)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(image.texture, image.position, Color.White);
    }//DrawImage
    public bool CheckForClick(GameImages rectangle)
    {

        if (mouse.Y < rectangle.position.Y + rectangle.texture.Height &&
            mouse.Y > rectangle.position.Y &&
            mouse.X > rectangle.position.X &&
            mouse.X < rectangle.position.X + rectangle.texture.Width)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }//CheckForClick

  StorageDevice device;  
  string containerName="MyGamesStorage";
  string filename = "mysave.sav";

  public struct SaveGame
  {

     public Vector2 buttonPosition;
     public Texture2D newbuttonTexture;

  }//Save Game


  private void InitiateSave()
  {
          device = null;
          StorageDevice.BeginShowSelector(PlayerIndex.One, this.SaveToDevice, null);
  }

  void SaveToDevice(IAsyncResult result)
  {
      device = StorageDevice.EndShowSelector(result);
      if (device != null && device.IsConnected)
      {
          SaveGame SaveData = new SaveGame()
          {
              buttonPosition = button.position,
              newbuttonTexture = button.texture,
          };
          IAsyncResult r = device.BeginOpenContainer(containerName, null, null);
          result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
          StorageContainer container = device.EndOpenContainer(r);
          if (container.FileExists(filename))
              container.DeleteFile(filename);
          Stream stream = container.CreateFile(filename);
          XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGame));
          serializer.Serialize(stream, SaveData);
          stream.Close();
          container.Dispose();
          result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
      }
  }


  private void InitiateLoad()
  {
          device = null;
          StorageDevice.BeginShowSelector(PlayerIndex.One, this.LoadFromDevice, null);
  }

  void LoadFromDevice(IAsyncResult result)
  {
      device = StorageDevice.EndShowSelector(result);
      IAsyncResult r = device.BeginOpenContainer(containerName, null, null);
      result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
      StorageContainer container = device.EndOpenContainer(r);
      result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
      if (container.FileExists(filename))
      {
          Stream stream = container.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open);
          XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGame));
          SaveGame SaveData = (SaveGame)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
          stream.Close();
          container.Dispose();
          //Update the game based on the save game file
          button.position = SaveData.buttonPosition;
          button.texture = SaveData.newbuttonTexture;
      }
  }

}
}
```

I've simplified and reproduced my problem in a smaller program so its easier to share.

When I run the program and Right click to save, then move the object's location a bit so I can see a change and then middle click to load the game, I get the error.

What I did to reproduce the error:

- Run the program
- Right Click - This saved the game
- Left click with the mouse past the bottom of the screen - This changes the button's image to "Catch - Red"
- Position mouse to the left of the screen so that the button moves
- Middle Click so that the game loads the previously saved data, the button should be centered with it's first image "button"

This is where I get the error message
ObjectdispsoedException was unhandled Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Texture2D'.
on the spriteBatch.End(); line.

Admittedly I did just copy and past the save and load classes from the internet, I don't know how each step fully works.

Goal for the code: I want to be able to save the data, such as location, assigned content, arrays etc. So that it can be loaded again later.

Comment: Until someone comes along with a better answer:

Since I'm having trouble with the content.load/images, I'm just going to save numeral variables and use those to reload the image data.
i.e; call a method that assigns an int variable,
    public int numImageSaver;
When the user hits the save button, assign the variable numImageSaver = 1;
Then in the savetodevice method, save numImageSaver,
when the user loads the data, grab the numImageSaver back from the variable in the save file.
Then call a method that will decipher the number with an if or switch
if(numImageSaver == 1){button.texture = ...)

Comment: After studying the code line by line, I realized that the savedata was not transferring the texture part of the GameImages.     To Get around this, I simply called a method after the variables get assigned data from the Savedata. This method must assign every texture that you plan to use on the current screen (if you do something(click/type) that loads or assigns a new texture you won't need to load that into this method.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be loading content in update. It should be done in "loadcontent", hence the name... You should load the 2 textures in load content and then swap them in update.

Second, the problem is where you set texture2D again in the load function. Because what content.load() does is loads the texture onto the graphics card. But if you reset it then the reference will change. This relates back to my first point. You should have already loaded the content when content.load is called. So you should separate the texture2d and the game objects.

For example (wont compile, but you get the idea):

```
class MyGameObject
{
   public int textureIndex = 0;
   public Vector2 position = new Vector2(0, 0);
}

class Game
{

  Texture2D[] textures;
  MyGameObject poop;

  void loadContent()
  {
    textures = new Texture2D[2];
    textures[0] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("a texture");
    textures[1] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("different texture");
    poop = new MyGameObject();
    poop.textureIndex = 0;
  }

  void update()
  {
     if (mouse.Y > 600)
     {
        poop.textureIndex = 1;
     }
  }

  void draw()
  {
     spriteBatch.draw(textures[poop.textureIndex], poop.position);
  }

  ....other stuff....
}
```

Comment: wow, this is easy to comprehend, but something I never knew. I don't know how I picked up such a bad way to load textures. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would there be anyway to easily loop through all my image resources?
Something like, for int i = 0; i<resources/images/number of files; i++) textures[i] = Content.Load<Texture2D>([Name of File after /images]);

Comment: EDIT: I've realized it'd be better for me to make multiple Texture2D arrays for the type of images.

Comment: It's worth you considering using an enum to define your texture indices, this would mean defining an enum and using an array of enum instead of int. This is good because it will be far easier to read and I think a good lesson at your current experience level. It is generally bad practise to use 'magic' numbers in code. *Feel free to mark my answer as correct ;) *

Comment: I've used enum for gamestates before, but I can't tell what the advantage or really what an enum is. I'll need to do some research on this. (is your answer using a 'magic' number?)

Comment: What I mean by that is that it is bad practice to have hard coded numbers: "this_variable = 2; that_variable = 5;". Far better is to have "this_variable = MyTextureEnum.Pig; that_variable = MyTextureEnum.Cat;". And I know its was my sample code...